# Psychoanalytic theories of female mentality based on childhood development?

Tags: psychoanalysis

I am interested in finding out what if any theories exist to explain female psychology in terms of childhood development and how those psychological traits are expressed in adult behavior.

For example, I have noticed that women who had a close or quasi-sexual relationship to their father when they were little girls have a tendency when adults to be demur and to hold their head down, but then to glance upwards at a man as though seeking approval. I also notice that such women are attracted to older men particularly. So, in other words, the nature of childhood experience a woman has seems to be reflected in her social behaviors as an adult.

Are there specific theories about this that attempt to delineate types of female mentality based on the style of upbringing or the nature of the household in which the female was brought up?

Answer (score 1):

I have started to piece together an answer to this question and am posting it for the benefit of anyone coming to the same subject:

Female Psychology: an annotated bibliography by Schuler

Feminine psychology by Karen Horney (1973)

The Female Brain by Brizendine (2006)

Psychology of Women: Behavior in a Biosocial Context (1977)

Female sexuality : the early psychoanalytic controversies (1999)

On the Psychology of Women : A Survey of Empirical Studies by Sherman (1974)